# Can I reapply for a master's degree If I already failed a master's degree?

Tags: masters, application, university

I heard that if you fail a master's degree, you'll have a tough time reapplying for another one. Is that true? I had a really bad experience with the one I'm doing currently (Artificial Intelligence msc) which I might fail, and I was wondering if I would be able to apply to another university afterwards in case that happens? I already have an undergraduate degree with first class honors in computer science (with plenty of AI modules I did really well on). I'm doing my masters degree in the same university I did my undergraduate in. Would I be able to hide the fact that I failed a masters?